# How to specify PDF page size using pdfkit in python

Tags: python, pdfkit, pos, python-pdfkit

I know in node we can do something set `size: [width,height]` like this.
But while I replace this in python
`options = {'page-size':'A4'}` with `options = {'page-size':[width,height]}`
I get an error.

I want to set a width of 60mm for POS

Comment: Try this: options= { 'page-height': '297mm', 'page-width': '210mm' } instead of 'page-size' for A4 or 'page-width': '60mm' for your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

as said [here](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) and [here](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt), the correct syntax is:

```
options = {
    'page-height': 'yourHeight',
    'page-width': 'yourWidth',
}
```